# JSON Parsing in android by appending a data

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse the JSON by using a keyvalue pair

- I am unable to parse because of log errors
- onclick of one button i go to nextactivity by taking a data which is
  passed to next tab activity
- The tabActivity takes that data to fetch information from the url by
  appending to it

---

**AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.java**

```
public class AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView extends TabActivity {

    // TabSpec Names
    private static final String INBOX_SPEC = "Rating";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        String REST = getIntent().getStringExtra("REST");

        // Inbox Tab
        TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(INBOX_SPEC);
        Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.class);
        inboxIntent.putExtra("REST", REST);
        inboxSpec.setIndicator(INBOX_SPEC);
        // Tab Content
        inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);


        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec);

        //Set the current value tab to default first tab
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


    }

}
```

**RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.java**

```
public class RatingDescriptionSearchActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String NAME = "rank";
    static String TYPE = "country";
    static String DISTANCE = "distance";
    static String RATING = "rating";
    static String FLAG = "flag";
    static String PRICE= "price";

    String url="http://54.218.73.244:7005/DescriptionSortedSearchRating/";

    String CITY;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        CITY = getIntent().getStringExtra("REST");


        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Fetching the information");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address

            String newurl = url + "?" + "Key=" + CITY;
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(newurl);

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put(RatingDescriptionActivity.NAME, jsonobject.getString("restaurantNAME"));
                    map.put(RatingDescriptionActivity.TYPE, jsonobject.getString("restaurantTYPE"));
                    map.put(RatingDescriptionActivity.FLAG, "http://54.218.73.244:7005/"+jsonobject.getString("restaurantIMAGE"));
                    map.put(RatingDescriptionActivity.DISTANCE, jsonobject.getString("restaurantDISTANCE"));
                    map.put(RatingDescriptionActivity.RATING, jsonobject.getString("restaurantRATING"));
                    map.put(RatingDescriptionActivity.PRICE, jsonobject.getString("restaurantPrice"));



                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**Searchpage.java**

```
public class SearchPage extends FragmentActivity {

    EditText mEdit;
    EditText City;
    Button Back;
    Button Search;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_page);

        City=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.CITY_ID);

        Back=(Button) findViewById(R.id.TopNavigationBarRestaurantSearchActivityBackButton);
        Back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Takes you to whichever activity launched C
                finish();
            }
        });

        Search=(Button) findViewById(R.id.SEARCH_BUTTON_ID);
        Search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent searchIntent=new Intent(SearchPage.this,AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.class);
                searchIntent.putExtra("REST",City.getText().toString());
                startActivity(searchIntent);
            }
        });




    }

    public void selectDate(View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
    }
    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID);
        mEdit.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
    }
    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, dd, mm+1);
        }
    }

}
```

{EDIT]
I have changed `jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(newurl);`

LOG::

```
    10-10 14:57:46.326: E/log_tag(1116): Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 65: http://54.218.73.244:7005/DescriptionSortedSearchRating/?Key=pune 
10-10 14:57:46.326: E/log_tag(1116): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 14:57:46.326: E/log_tag(1116): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-10 14:57:46.326: W/dalvikvm(1116): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at com.project.findmybuffet.RatingDescriptionSearchActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.java:81)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at com.project.findmybuffet.RatingDescriptionSearchActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.java:1)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-10 14:57:46.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     ... 4 more
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116): Activity com.project.findmybuffet.AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405b70f8 that was originally added here
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.project.findmybuffet.AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405b70f8 that was originally added here
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RatingDescriptionSearchActivity$DownloadJSON.onPreExecute(RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.java:67)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.onCreate(RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.java:50)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at com.project.findmybuffet.AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.onCreate(AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.java:59)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-10 14:57:50.696: E/WindowManager(1116):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: error on `RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.java:81` , which line is it?

Comment: populateSetDate(yy, dd, mm+1);

Comment: i can't find it, probably you told me `SearchPage.java:81` but i m asking for `RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.java:81`.

Comment: oops sorry .... it is .. jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("restaurants");

Comment: i guess `jsonobject` is `NULL`. Just try to print it in `LogCat`.

Comment: http://54.218.73.244:7005/DescriptionSortedSearchRating/?Key=Pune   .... check that ... its a working url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first error is

> Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 65: `http://54.218.73.244:7005/DescriptionSortedSearchRating/?Key=pune`

It is due to the extra space at the end of the query. Try to trim the string before adding it (or, even better, use URLEncoder on the CITY parameter).

Comment: please check that url in ur browswer . it is correct format & works !

Comment: yes, because your browser takes care of that sort of things. Please simply try to put CITY.trim() in your newUrl.

Comment: Yes that ... worked ..... Thank you so much .... i spent... one entire day on this ... your solution ... gave a breakthrough :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(newurl);
```

instead of

```
 jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("newurl");
```

because currently you are passing `newurl` instead of value of newurl String to `getJSONfromURL`

as in updated log :

> Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal
>   character in query at index 65:
>   .....DescriptionSortedSearchRating/?Key=pune

so remove `/` from end of url

Comment: I made the changes .... still i have the same errors ... Please have a look at the updated LOG in question

Comment: please check that urlin your browser ... it is correct and works

Comment: @smriti2 : please try it as :`String url="http://54.218.73.244:7005/DescriptionSortedSearchRating/"+URLEncoder.encode("?Key=pune", "utf-8");`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : you are encoding the whole query, which will encode the ? and = as well. I think only the value needs to be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
       JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(str_response_starter);

    JSONArray json_array_item_id = jObject.getJSONArray("itemid");
    System.out.println("json array item id"+json_array_item_id);
```

It will be better if you provide your json format . JSON can be parse by use of collection